# Thymeleaf SEC tag not recognized in SpringBootStarter

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have two project, one is mine and the other is the book example.

Both project use Gradle and in my project `sec` tag are not recognized.
All is totally equals except for:

My project (in build.gradle) use:

1. springBootVersion = '1.3.0.RELEASE'
2. gradleVersion = '2.7'
3. `compile('org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3:2.1.2.RELEASE')`

The downloaded project (where security tag works) use:

1. springBootVersion = '1.2.5.RELEASE'
2. gradleVersion = '2.3'
3. compile 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3'

In both pages i have the sec:namespace defined:

```
xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3"
```

Comment: Upgrade to the `springsecurity4` tags as that is what the newer Spring Boot uses.

Answer (score 0):

Namespace for thymeleaf springsecurity3 and springsecurity4 is the same:

```
xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security"
```